# Python: functions of built in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to use Beautiful Soup to parse the html file.

First I made:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

but I had error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

so I made just:

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

and everything worked good. My question is: what is and difference between the BeautifulSoup imported from bs4 and imported directly? Is bs4 a built in library for python > 2.7?

Then I made :

```
data = url.openUrl("http://emma-watson.net")
self.soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
links = self.soup.find_all('a')
```

But I have an error:

```
links = self.soup.find_all('a')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

But I don't understand where is my mistake, because I took this line from the documentation. Functions like soup.find, soup.a, soup. p works ok, so what is wrong with this function?

Comment: you have bs3 installed

Comment: Hint: `soup` and `self.soup` don't refer to the same value.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, my mistake, but in my code I had the same self.soup and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bs4` and `BeautifulSoup` are *different major versions* of the same project. Both are *add-on* modules you need to install separately.

- `bs4` is BeautifulSoup version 4, the current major version.
- `BeautifulSoup` is version 3 at most, a version no longer maintained; the last release was over 2 years ago.

I recommend you install BeautifulSoup 4; it supports Python 3, pluggable parsers, and CSS selector syntax, as well as many bug fixes. BeautifulSoup 4 also cleaned up the naming conventions of methods used. See the [version 4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

In your code you are using BeautifulSoup 4 syntax; BeautifulSoup 3 is interpreting this as a search for the first tag `<find_all>` and returns `None` because it didn't find any. It would do this for any attribute it doesn't recognize.

In BeautifulSoup 3, you'd have to use [`soup.findAll()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) instead.

Comment: @ Thanks for explanation about bs4 and bs3. But I also made an edit, because writting the code here i just forgot to add 'self' before soup, but in my code it is the same but still doesn't work

Comment: @Rop: The problem is with the spelling of the method; there is no `find_all` method in BeautifulSoup 3.